How to copy files from one location to another using powershell and skipping files that are corrupt or that cannot be read?
I am looking to use powershell to copy all file from one location to another, however sometimes a file in the current directory is corrupt and cannot be copied. Powershell seems to stop and not continue to copy or just skip the file that is corrupt.
I am using this command: cp * '\\mycomp.local\Location\' -Recurse
I get this error:

There are 14 files in the current directory, only 5 get copied as the 6th is the file that is corrupt.
It works when I click and drag because I am able to 'Skip' corrupt files.

I want to be able to 'Skip' corrupt files and have powershell try and copy everything else.
NOTE: The -ErrorAction parameter does not work
I have used the -ErrorAction paramter in the following sequence:
cp * '\mycomp.local\Location' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
I also tried:
cp * '\mycomp.local\Location' -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore
I have also used try{code} catch{continue} with no success as well.

Show us the arguments you are using. The -ErrorAction parameter is supposed to work when used correctly, and we cannot tell how you have used it.

I use it as follows:  cp * '\mycomp.local\Location' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
I also tried: cp * '\mycomp.local\Location' -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore

That information need to be in the question body. Please use the EDIT button to make your question more complete and clear.

In case it might help, it seems you can launch ROBOCOPY from PowerShell ( https://www.codingref.com/article/powershell-robocopy ).  Robocopy has /R:nnn and /W:nnn parameters that let you set how many times it will Retry and how long it will wait between retries. I have a few Mac-generated files on my NAS that Robocopy (and everything else I've tried) barfs on. Setting /R:1 or 0 and /W:1 gets past them and on to the next files.

Copy one file at a time in a loop, in a try catch block.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | foreach { try { $_ | cp * '\mycomp.local\Location' }  catch { Write-Warning 'corrupted File' } }


I did modify you code which appeared to work in my particular scenario as:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | foreach { try {cp $_ '\mycomp.local\Location' } catch {Write-Warning 'Corrupted File'}}
